# SQL Query to Insert a column value which treat as reference ID

Tags: mysql

Hello friends I know its a silly question. But my mind is stop working and I am stuck at this position.If anyone having any solution for this question please help me.

I want solution  for both  `Mysql` as well as `SQL Server`

I have a table called refference having structure

```
id          int(10)     AUTO_INCREMENT   
reff_id     varchar(100)         
pid         int(11)
```

Where

`id` - The auto increment value

`reff_id` - This is a unique string having this format XYZ#ddmmyyyy`id` (where id is the same rows id (the auto increment value) ) and XYZ is any random string having length 3

`pid` - which is the foreign key to a table called  `product`

I need a single Query to insert the value into the table and the query must insert `reff_id` dynamically with above logic .

Any help appreciate . :) :)

N.B

I want a single query which is compute the value of `reff_id` at the time of insertion where the date format is represented the current date

Comment: You want the date in reff_id inserted in other table?

Comment: nope I want a single query which is compute the value of reff_id at the time of insertion where the date format is represented the current date

Comment: To be clear: "XYZ is any random string" -- you want an answer that crafts a *random* three-character code from the characters "A" through "Z", then concatenates it together with a '#' character, an 8-digit date, and the auto_increment value?  Or does is the "randoom" code not actually "random" but coming from elsewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a way to do what you are planning to do but it may fail if there are concurrent access/insertions to the same table.

MySQL version:

```
INSERT INTO refference (reff_id, pid)
VALUES (
   CONCAT('XYZ#', DATE_FORMAT(now(),"%d%m%Y"), CAST(
    (SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT FROM information_schema.TABLES 
    WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA=DATABASE() AND TABLE_NAME='refference') 
    AS CHAR)), 1
)
```

SQL Server version:

```
INSERT INTO refference (reff_id, pid)
VALUES (
   'XYZ#' + REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 103), '/', '') + CAST(
    (SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('refference')+1) 
    AS VARCHAR(30))), 1
)
```

These are prone to problems due to concurrency because if multiple users are inserting at the same time then AUTO_INCREMENT / IDENT_CURRENT value may get changed between execution of the SELECT and INSERT statements. Auto increment value is not generated till a new record is actually inserted into a table.

A better way to do is to use TRIGGERS, meaning that you insert an empty row and then UPDATE the record to SET reff_id column. There you may use the [`LAST_INSERT_ID()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) (mysql) and [`@@IDENTITY`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187342.aspx) (sql sever) functions.

Comment: check now .@Aziz Shaikh

Answer (score 2):

Should work with some corrections... didn't test it

```
INSERT INTO  refference (reff_id, pid)
SELECT CONCAT(substring('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', FLOOR(RAND() * 26), 1),
              substring('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', FLOOR(RAND() * 26), 1),
              substring('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', FLOOR(RAND() * 26), 1), 
              '#',
              DATE_FORMAT(now(), '%d%m%Y'),
              `AUTO_INCREMENT`),
        your_pid
FROM information_schema.tables 
WHERE table_name='refference' -- Can end here if only 1 DB 
AND table_schema = DATABASE();  -- If > 1 DB
```